# Feedback on automatic form filling with reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

**Context:**

I need to fill a handful of .docx templates with answers that come from **form.responses**, which is a dynamic object that comes from a JSON and can have different properties that vary according to the type of the form that was answered.

To do the filling, we need to instantiate a DTO called BindDto that takes the template string (eg.: ${PersonName}) and the value that will replace it (eg.: form.responses.client_name = "John Doe").

In my case, I created some **[X]Constants** classes that have properties that look like this...

```
public static readonly KeyValuePair<string, string> PERSON_NAME = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_name", "${PersonName}");
public static readonly KeyValuePair<string, string> PERSON_AGE = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("my_age", "${PersonAge}");
public static readonly KeyValuePair<string, string> MOTHER_NAME = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("mother", "${MotherName}");
```

...to map which template string each field from the JSON correponds to.

The code below was written so I could fill all the templates independent from which fields they might have by searching the **[X]Constants** classes and using the KeyValuePairs that I have set.

It works (o' course), but it seems I little... *clumsy*. And I don't have enough knowledge about C# to be sure this isn't pure madness.

What do you think about this code? Is it valid? Is is overengineering? How can I improve it?

I don't think performance will ever be a concern, but I would like to be enlightened in that sense too.

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to discuss it!

```
public List<BindDto> GenerateBinds(IEnumerable<Form> forms)
{
    var constants = new List<FieldInfo>();
    var binds = new List<BindDto>();

    constants.AddRange(typeof(AuthConsts).GetFields());
    constants.AddRange(typeof(ClientConsts).GetFields());
    constants.AddRange(typeof(ContactConsts).GetFields());
    constants.AddRange(typeof(AddressConsts).GetFields());
    constants.AddRange(typeof(ReferenceConsts).GetFields());

    foreach (var form in forms)
    {
        var formResponses = form.response.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();

        IEnumerable<string> formFields = formResponses.Keys;

        foreach (var field in formFields)
        {
            foreach (var constant in constants)
            {
                if (constant.FieldType == typeof(KeyValuePair<string, string>))
                {
                    var templateString = (KeyValuePair<string, string>)constant.GetValue(this);

                    if (templateString.Key == field)
                        binds.Add(new BindDto(templateString.Value, formResponses[field]));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return binds;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just to tell you upfront, your code looks good, is easy to read and everything is well named. But it can be improved nevertheless.

First thing, `public` methods should always validate its method arguments. Passing `null` would lead to a nasty `NullReferenceException` at the start of the most outer `foreach` loop.

I would suggest making the `constants` a class level variable being filled in the constructor, because the types won't usually change while your code is running.

By restricting `FieldType` of the `constants` to `KeyValuePair<string, string>` will eliminate the `if` inside the most inner loop and will limit the `constants` to a smaller number.

Omitting braces `{}` although they may be optional can be dangerous because it may lead to hidden and therfor hard to find bugs. I would like to encourage you to use them.

Implementing the mentioned points will look like this

```
private readonly List<FieldInfo> constants = new List<FieldInfo>();
public ctor()
{
    constants.AddRange(typeof(AuthConsts).GetFields());
    constants.AddRange(typeof(ClientConsts).GetFields());
    constants.AddRange(typeof(ContactConsts).GetFields());
    constants.AddRange(typeof(AddressConsts).GetFields());
    constants.AddRange(typeof(ReferenceConsts).GetFields());
}

public List<BindDto> GenerateBinds(IEnumerable<Form> forms)
{
    if (forms == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(forms)); }

    var neededType = typeof(KeyValuePair<string, string>);
    var binds = new List<BindDto>();
    var keyValueConstants = constants.Where(c => c.FieldType == neededType);

    foreach (var form in forms)
    {
        var formResponses = form.response.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();

        IEnumerable<string> formFields = formResponses.Keys;

        foreach (var field in formFields)
        {
            foreach (var constant in keyValueConstants)
            {
                var templateString = (KeyValuePair<string, string>)constant.GetValue(this);

                if (templateString.Key == field)
                {
                    binds.Add(new BindDto(templateString.Value, formResponses[field]));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return binds;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition of @Heslacher points, I would say the way you're handling the constants is making you doing extra work.

```
public static readonly KeyValuePair<string, string> PERSON_NAME = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_name", "${PersonName}");
public static readonly KeyValuePair<string, string> PERSON_AGE = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("my_age", "${PersonAge}");
public static readonly KeyValuePair<string, string> MOTHER_NAME = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("mother", "${MotherName}");
```

Using the above can be simplified in a `Dictionary`. So, you can combine them to this :

```
public static readonly Dictionary<string, string> Person_Info = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "client_name", "${PersonName}" },
    { "my_age", "${PersonAge}" },
    { "mother", "${MotherName}" }
};
```

With this, you can get the constant value like this :

```
var key = "mother";

if(Person_Info.TryGetValue(key, out string _value))
{
    // do something with the value
}
```

So, if you go to each class in `[X]Constants classes` and combine the `KeyValuePair<string, string>` you'll flatten your classes, and might end up with one class that holds multiple `Dictionary` properties, which will make things even simpler to access, and If the `keys` are unique in all classes, you can combine them all in one dictionary, so you can have one method that will process all the bindings process.

```
public IEnumerable<BindDto> GenerateBinds(IEnumerable<Form> forms)
{
    // for demoenstration only when using Dictionary<string,string> .
    var constants = ConstsClass.ConstantsDictionary; 


    foreach (var form in forms)
    {
        var formResponses = form.response.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();

        foreach (var field in formResponses.Keys)
        {
            if(constants.TryGetValue(field, out string _value))
            {       
                yield return new BindDto(_value, formResponses[field]);
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

With the `Dictionary` approach, you'll also eliminate the need of using reflection. If you need multiple dictionaries, you can adjust your method, and add a dictionary argument so you can pass the correct dictionary something like this :

```
public IEnumerable<BindDto> GenerateBinds(IEnumerable<Form> forms, IDictionary<string, string> constants)
{
    foreach (var form in forms)
    {
        var formResponses = form.response.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();

        foreach (var field in formResponses.Keys)
        {
            if(constants.TryGetValue(field, out string _value))
            {       
                yield return new BindDto(_value, formResponses[field]);
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are totally right! The extense list of KeyValuePairs approach was a remain from an early implementation attempt and I kind of forgot I wouldn't need it to be like this anymore. The use of dictionaries made the code way more simple -- no overengineering with reflection anymore. Thank you so much!